# What service does Multibit connect to?

Tags: client, thin-clients

Multibit is clearly a faster desktop wallet since it's a thin client that doesn't download and process the entire *8GB blockchain.

My question is, what service does Multibit connect to in order to process transactions? Are there security concerns to be aware of compared to using a thick client with its own blockchain? What benefits are there using a thick client (like Bitcoin-QT) compared to a thin client?

Answer (score 1):

Multibit uses SPV, which is a peer-to-peer protocol consisting of two parts.

- It downloads the block headers from peers (not the whole block). This allows it to verify that the blocks have a lot of hashing power behind them, and get the merkle root for each of them.
- It asks peers for transactions matching the addresses it cares about. It can verify that the transactions belong to one of the blocks it knows about by using the merkle root.

[See here for a discussion of the security tradeoffs.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Scalability#Simplified_payment_verification)